How to get Java Testcontainers work with ComposeContainer and R2DBC Postgres in Spring Boot?
Running my code locally works perfect. I'm using R2DBC togther with postgres for this.
My normal compose.yml file looks like this:
services:
  my-db:
    container_name: my-db
    userns_mode: keep-id:uid=1001,gid=1001
    image: bitnami/postgresql:16.3.0
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - my-net

networks:
  my-net:


Now I wanted to use testcontainers for which I have src/test/resources/compose.yml:
services:
  my-db:
    extends:
      file: ../../../compose.yml
      service: my-db
    env_file: .env
networks:
  my-net:

My test class currently looks like this:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ApiApplicationTests {
    @Container
    public static ComposeContainer environment = new ComposeContainer(
            new File("src/test/resources/compose.yml"))
            .withExposedService("my-db", 5432, Wait.forListeningPort())
            .withLocalCompose(true);
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}

Which keeps getting me
INFO tc.docker --  Network gicdzpqgd9bm_my-net  Created
INFO tc.docker --  Container my-db  Creating
INFO tc.docker --  Container my-db  Created
INFO tc.docker --  Container my-db  Starting
INFO tc.docker --  Container my-db  Started
NFO tc.docker -- Docker Compose has finished running
1:26:45.431 [main] INFO tc.alpine/socat:1.7.4.3-r0 -- Creating container for image: alpine/socat:1.7.4.3-r0
01:26:45.449 [main] ERROR tc.alpine/socat:1.7.4.3-r0 -- Could not start container
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Aborting attempt to link to container gicdzpqgd9bm-my-db-1 as it is not running

I can't find any way to get it working and similar issues on Github didn't help me any further.
Am I missing something? Should this even be working this way?

Both containers my-db and the exposed port for alpine/socat are trying to listen on port 5432. The testcontainer is started first and succeeds. my-db comes in second and fails.
Remove/change the listening port from one of the definitions.

The only way I get it though is by removing .withExposedService("my-db", 5432, Wait.forListeningPort()).
Then R2DBC isn't able to make any connection at all...
What worked was removing it comlpetely and using the URL scheme approach, though I'd prefer using my adjusted testing compose.yml setup...
